# Как сохранить картинку тепловой карты matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Мне нужно сохранить тепловую карту в виде картинки в matplotlib:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как я пытаюсь это сделать:

```
plt.imshow(my_matrix, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('E:\\test.png', transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

Аргумент `transparent=True` делает прозрачным фон изображения, но все же остается шкала значений и масштаб осей. Как я могу сохранить непосредственно картинку тепловой карты матрицы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем вы используете plt.colorbar, если она вам не нужна? уберите ее из кода. затем:

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("filname.png", transparent=True)
```

все.

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало

Answer (score 2):

К ответу от [strawdog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/311069/strawdog) я только добавлю, что если вы хотите избавиться *только от шкалы значений* в `colorbar`, примените к нему метод `.set_ticks([])`, т.е. вместо вашего

```
plt.colorbar()
```

используйте

```
plt.colorbar().set_ticks([])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]